# MongoDb aggregation condition based on elements in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql, aggregate

Following is the structure of my document:

```
{
   _id:1,
   testId:3,
   marksObtained:10,
   subjects:[
     {
        subjectId:1,
        marksObtained:6
     },
     {
        subjectId:2,
        marksObtained:4
     }
   ]
}
```

Now, I need to calculate the number of students who scored higher for each subject and update it in the document. I am able to do this on the test level but unable to figure out how to do it on the level of array element.

So lets say there's one students who has score higher for subject 1 and 2 students who scored higher for subject to, I need to modify the document to look like the following:

```
{
   _id:1,
   testId:3,
   marksObtained:10,
   subjects:[
     {
        subjectId:1,
        marksObtained:6,
        rank:2
     },
     {
        subjectId:2,
        marksObtained:4,
        rank:3
     }
   ]
}
```